# Does a comparative always need to compare with something?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, semantics, comparatives

As I understand it, comparatives compare with something. So something that is *colder* is *more cold* than another thing. However, can't a word like *colder* be used as an adjective without being compared to something else? For example, is it ungrammatical to say the following?

> People who live in *colder* climates should be careful about their
>   heating bills.

The adjective *cold* could be inserted in place of *colder*, but I think the meaning would be different. To me *colder* sounds like 'somewhat cold' as opposed to 'absolute cold.' 
So my questions are as follows: 
1. Is this use of *colder* grammatical?
2. If so, is it still considered a comparative?
3. Do you agree with my understanding of *colder* vs. *cold* in the example?

Comment: I think *colder* here just means *colder than average*. There's an implicit comparison.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, the name comparative does not proscribe the valency. It is just the form that is used when you are comparing two things.

In cases when you have one thing it can still be used.

Following cases are typical:
- we want to compare to *some* average
- the thing we are comparing to is already established from the context
- we want to be deliberately vague

In this case it is called [null comparative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative#Null_comparative).

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. Basically, you *are* comparing to something, you're just allowing the audience to infer what exactly that is.

Comment: That's exactly it, a null comparative. I should have read further down the wikipedia article myself when I was looking it up. Thanks

Comment: @Dusty, yes I agree you not comparing *explicitly*, but *implicitly* (unless in case of established names e.g. *Greater metropolitan area* - though even those were established through comparison).

Comment: Aside: the null comparative is a favorite form in advertisements, because it tends to build up the product while still being vague about what is being said, and avoids explicitly mentioning competing products.

Answer (score 6):

1. It is grammatical.
2. Yes, it is still the comparative form of the adjective *cold*.
3. Although no other climates are mentioned, there is an implied comparison with climates that are not so cold. Colder climates could include the coldest ones, so to that extent some colder climates could be more than 'somewhat cold'.