# Why "Greater Toronto" rather than "Great Toronto"

Tags: word-choice, etymology, adjectives, names, comparatives

Many big cities have their names preceded by *Greater*. Why not just *Great*? Does *Greater* indicate that the city is ambitious to expand itself?

Why is *Greater* not used for country names such as *Great Britain*? Is it just due to historical reasons?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46387/does-a-comparative-always-need-to-compare-with-something

Comment: Because even people from GTA would laugh at "Great Toronto" ?

Comment: @MartinBeckett People from the city of Toronto would like that! What a compliment! Hehe :)

Comment: Because only Britain is Great?

Comment: @SimonRichter Ever heard of [Greater Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Poland)?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In this context (greater Toronto) *greater* means “an area greater than the city itself” and “*greater* Toronto” is a shortened version of “the greater Toronto area”. *Greater* describes/modifies *area* rather than *Toronto*, giving a size contrast (*greater*) rather than describing the goodness of the city (*great*).

Comment: In fact, GTA is the most common name for 416+905, followed by "the Greater Toronto Area" and in third place "Greater Toronto." I have also seen "Greater London" in the UK.

Comment: But great doesn't mean good in Great Britain either, it means big.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Exactly. "Good-ness" has nothing to do with either Great (Britain) or Greater (Toronto/Manchester/London) in this question.

Comment: "Greater" is relative - it's greater *than* something else. With "Great Britain" (guess) maybe there's no "Lesser Britain" to be greater than? It's greater than something else (England, Scotland or Wales indivually) but *not* greater than a smaller thing called "Britain". IIRC "Britain" and "Great Britain" are synonyms. In any case, it's history - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain#Derivation_of_.22Great.22

Comment: @Steve314 "Britain" and "Great Britain" are sometimes synonyms, but ironically often "Britain" is used as an abbreviation for the larger "Great Britain and Northern Ireland". ("Great Britain" is England, Wales and Scotland.)

Comment: @Steve314 : Actually Brittany is often considered as "Lesser Britain"

Comment: Greater (city) means the city and the surrounding metropolitan area, including suburbs. Kinda surprised you didn't mention suburbs in this answer.

Answer (score 26):

*Great* means *big*, *greater* means *bigger*.

So *Greater Manchester* is the larger metropolitan area around the city of Manchester in the middle.

However, *Great Britain* is the larger of the two separate and distinct Britains, the other being Brittany in north-west France. In French, Great Britain is *Grande Bretagne* and Brittany is just *Bretagne*. Brittany has also been referred to as  *Less, Lesser* or *Little Britain*.

Comment: It's not about larger but older.  Yes, older brother is usually larger.

Answer (score 20):

The answer is that the expression is based on how we, as humans, interpret geography.  We refer to smaller, relatively unknown areas by the name of a larger, more well-known, area the smaller area is near.

By saying "Greater Toronto", we identify the city of Toronto and the smaller areas close by, at the same time acknowledging that these smaller areas are  not, in reality, part of the city of Toronto.  It is the same as saying "Toronto and its surrounding suburbs."

This nature can be observed when meeting someone unfamiliar to the area in question.  If Sally lived in the suburbs of Washington DC, and met somebody from California at a conference, Sally would say "I'm from Washington DC", even though she lives in Falls Church, VA, and does not live within the boundaries of the city.

When someone asks me where I live, I would respond with "Charleston, WV" even though I don't live within the city limits, and the city is a 20 minute drive from my home.

Comment: This one really distinguishes itself from other answers!!

Comment: +1, but I think you've got your second sentence mixed around. We're referring to a *larger* area by the name of the *smaller*, well-known area.

Comment: @DCShannon, it is how one looks at the issue.  When I said smaller areas, I was not speaking of the total population or area that identifies with the well-known area, but rather each the smaller enclaves that surround the larger, more well-known place.  When one looks at them in aggregate, they are larger than and more populous than the more well-known areas.

Comment: Alright, that seems a bit awkward, but I see what you're saying. Basically "refer to smaller, relatively unknown areas *and* a larger, more well-known area the smaller area is near by the name of the larger".

Comment: @DCShannon, exactly.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_municipalities_in_the_Greater_Toronto_Area

Answer (score 10):

*Greater* means “the metropolitan area surrounding”. “Greater Toronto” refers to Toronto and its suburbs.

*Great* does not mean the area surrounding. It is used in the name “Great Britain” to distinguish it from “Little Britain”, a.k.a. Brittany.

Comment: I know what it means, but why choose the word "Greater" rather than "Great"?

Comment: Great Britain is not a metropolitan area surrounding Little Britain (Brittany). Check a map.

Answer (score 6):

In the phrase *greater Toronto* the adjective *greater* is not describing Toronto itself; the phrase as a whole refers to the urban area which includes Toronto.  Thus it includes the small cities and suburbs within the entire built-up area in and adjoining the central city.

The phrase "great Toronto" would be taken as a description of Toronto itself.  *Great* is a simple adjective; *greater* is a comparative.  So the phrase *greater Toronto* is comparing Toronto to something else; the implicit something else is the entire urban area, which of course is larger.

Comment: +1 *Great Toronto* would be at best ambiguous, and at worst misunderstood.

Comment: If you lived just outside Toronto you wouldn't consider it ambiguous, it's just wrong :-)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the list of any areas that could be referred to as "Toronto." Then, find the greater of these - the largest one.  This is the "Greater Toronto area".  This is in contrast to "Toronto Proper", which would be within the area defined in some document as explicitly being Toronto, and would not include outlying areas, even if they are just a kilometer from the border.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of correct answers. A simple way of thinking of this simply to ask "Greater than what, eh?" - the answer being "Greater than the city of Toronto proper." Include Mississauga, Oakville, etc, etc..

Comment: +1 With a little hindsight, people can certainly come up with more and more beautifully crafted answers!